# What would the following display in scheme?

Tags: scheme, lisp

I have tried this expression on a few (online) scheme interpreters/parsers and sometimes get different answers. For the following expression:

```
(display "okkk") \; "ok;" ;"ok"
```

What would it display and/or return? Why? For example:

- Are `\` acceptable outside of an s-expression, and do they escape the next character?
- How is a string interpreted outside an expression, or is that invalid?

Comment: It seems to be really unclear whether, for instance `\;` is an identifier or not, or in general whether `\` is allowed as an escape for symbols/identifiers.  It looks to me that in R5RS at least it's not, but I bet a lot of implementations allow it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That probably depends on what Scheme syntax your implementation may support.

One might for example expect:

```
(display "okkk")    -> displays okkk
\;                  -> error: unbound variable
"ok;"               -> displays nothing, but returns the string
;"ok"               -> end of line comment
```

Comment: so is ``\`` not allowed outside a string or comment?

Comment: @David542: not necessarily. In Chez Scheme it says unbound variable. So it's legal, but there is no variable value for it (unless one has defined one earlier).